# UPDATE mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I have these lines of code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET txnid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['txn_id']) . "',
  payment_amount='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['payment_amount']) . "' ,
  payment_status='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['payment_status']) . "',
  itemid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['item_number']) . "',
  createdtime='" . mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) . "' WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE["buy_user"]) . "'";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I'm trying to update the id 117.

I know I have to use UPDATE but I can not do it.

Help me

Comment: Where's your UPDATE?

Comment: So you want to do `UPDATE \`user\` WHERE \`id\`=117` instead of `INSERT INTO \`users\` VALUES()`?

Comment: Can you please post the error, as well? Is it in logs?

Comment: You are essentially trying to do a query on a query -> `mysql_query(mysql_query()` as you have `$sql = mysql_query(...); $result = mysql_query($sql);`. Either remove the 2nd line, or remove the `mysql_query()` from around the query string. Also, you are missing the closing `)` from the `mysql_query(` around the `$sql` query string.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, you're calling `mysql_query` function twice.

I recommend you follow this pattern:

```
 # set a variable to contain just a string, the SQL text you want to execute
 $sql = "UPDATE ... ";

 # the SQL text is conveniently available for debugging/logging
 echo $sql;

 # execute the SQL
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
```